# Time to event analysis

Tags: survival

If we want to study about how many times of silicone vessel model for arterial blood gas simulator that can be punctured until they have structure failure such as hole or fluid leak.Can we use statistics like survival analysis in SPSS ?

Comment: Survival analysis is not a "statistic:" it is a set of related procedures.  What would be helpful to know, indeed, is what statistics -- or even better, what data -- you have available.

Comment: Knowing more about the nature of the data you have (or would be able to collect) would be helpful. I suspect that it isn't just the number of punctures but also the age of the vessel and its history of stresses/pressures would also be important. A form of survival analysis might be helpful, but the nature of the data will determine whether, and if so what type of survival analysis. Please provide that information by editing your question, as comments are easy to overlook and (unlike questions) can get completely deleted.